# Array not returning value

Tags: java, arrays

Hi first time poster and java beginner.

**Problem**: Attempting to return the count value of student marks using  **gradeDistn** method

The gradeDistn method will accept an array of characters, which are the grades assigned for the array of marks, such as returned by the grades method. The gradeDistn method will return an array of integer values containing the distribution of grades, which is the number of occurrences of each grade in the assigned grades. The characters used for grades are fixed. The returned array should provide the distribution in order from grade A to grade F

***Output***

Min is 24

Max is 97

Range is 74

Mean is 62

Median is 62

Mode is 53

FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEEEEEDDDDDDDDDDCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Distribution of Marks

A: 1

B: 1

C: 1

D: 1

E: 1

F: 1

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;



    public class Marks {

private static final int NMARKS = 125;
private static final double mean = 65.0;
private static final double std = 15.0;

/**
 * Returns an array of NMARKS integer marks approximately normally distributed,
 * with specified mean (mean) and standard deviation (std),
 * and with values outside 0..100 removed.
 * @return the array of marks.
 */
public static int[] getMarks() {
    Random rand = new Random(1001L);
    int mark;
    int[] theMarks = new int[NMARKS];
    int n = 0;
    while (n < NMARKS) {
        mark = (int) Math.round(std*rand.nextGaussian() + mean);
        if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100)
            theMarks[n++] = mark;
    }
    return theMarks;
}

/**
 * Test code
 * @param args not used
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] testMarks = getMarks();


    int[] sortedMarks = arraySort (testMarks);
    System.out.println("Unsorted marks\n");
    for (int n = 0; n < testMarks.length; n++) {
        System.out.print(testMarks[n] + " ");
        if (n % 10 == 9)
            System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nSorted marks\n");

    for (int n = 0; n < sortedMarks.length; n++) {
        System.out.print(sortedMarks[n] + " ");
        if (n % 10 == 9)
            System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");

    //Print Minimum
    int minimum = getMin(getMarks());
    System.out.println("Min is " + minimum);

    //Print Maximum
    int maximum = getMax(getMarks());
    System.out.println("Max is " + maximum);

    //Print Range
    int range = (getRange(maximum, minimum));
    System.out.println("Range is " + range);

    //Print Mean
    int mean = getMean(getMarks());
    System.out.println("Mean is " + mean);

    //Print Median
    int median = getMedian(sortedMarks);
    System.out.println("Median is " + median);

    //Print Mode
    int mode = getMode(sortedMarks);
    System.out.println("Mode is " + mode);

    //Print Grades
    char[] grades = getGrades(sortedMarks);
    System.out.println(grades);
    //Print gradeDistn

    int[] gradeDistrubution = gradeDistn(grades);

    System.out.println("Distribution of Marks\nA: " + gradeDistrubution[0] + "\nB: " + gradeDistrubution[1] + "\nC: " + 
            gradeDistrubution[2] + "\nD: " + gradeDistrubution[3] + "\nE: " + gradeDistrubution[4] + 
            "\nF: " + gradeDistrubution[5]);


}

//getMin method will return the minimum mark
public static int getMin(int[] inputArray){
    int minValue = inputArray[0];
    for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){
        if(inputArray[i] <minValue){
            minValue = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;

}   
//getMax method will return the maximum mark
public static int getMax(int[] inputArray){
    int maxValue = inputArray[0];
    for(int i=1;i < inputArray.length;i++){
        if(inputArray[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = inputArray[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;

}
//getRange method will find the difference between the maximum and minimum marks
public static int getRange(int maxNum, int minNum){
    int max = maxNum;
    int min = minNum;
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return range;

}

//getMean method will return the average of marks
public static int getMean(int[] inputArray){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i: inputArray){
        total += i;
    }
    return total/(inputArray.length);

}

// arraySort method sorts the array of grades in numerical ascending order
public static int [] arraySort(int [] inputArray){
    int [] sortedArray = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length); 
    Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
    return sortedArray;


}
//getMedian method will return the median value of the set of marks
public static int getMedian(int[] inputArray){
    int listLength = inputArray.length;
    int x = listLength / 2;
    int median = inputArray[x];

    return median; 

}

//getMode method will return the mode of the set of marks, which is the most commonly occurring mark
public static int getMode(int[] n) {
    int maxValue = 0;
    int maxCounts = 0;
    int[] counts = new int[n.length];

    for (int i=0; i < n.length; i++) {
        counts[n[i]]++;
        if (maxCounts < counts[n[i]]) {
            maxCounts = counts[n[i]];
            maxValue = n[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

/*grades method will return an array of characters which are the grades 
  corresponding to the integer marks in the array of marks */
public static char [] getGrades(int[] n){
    int[] grades = new int[n.length]; 
    char[] marks = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    char[] convertedGrades = new char[n.length];


    for (int i = 0 ; i < grades.length; i++){
        grades [i] = i;
        if (grades[i] >= 90)                                        
            convertedGrades[i] = marks[0];
        else if (grades[i] >= 75)                                       
            convertedGrades[i] = marks[1];
        else if (grades[i] >= 60)                                       
            convertedGrades[i] = marks[2];
        else if (grades[i] >= 50)                                       
            convertedGrades[i] = marks[3];
        else if (grades[i] >= 45)                                       
            convertedGrades[i] = marks[4];
        else                                    
            convertedGrades[i] = marks[5];
    }
     return convertedGrades; 
}

// GRADESDISTN METHOD
public static int[] gradeDistn(char[] arr){
    char[] characterArray = new char[arr.length]; 
    int A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0,E=0,F=0;

    for (char i = 0 ; i < characterArray.length; i++){
        characterArray [i] = i;
        if (characterArray[i] == 'A')
            A++;
        if (characterArray[i] == 'B')
            B++;
        if (characterArray[i] == 'C')
            C++;
        if (characterArray[i] == 'D')
            D++;
        if (characterArray[i] == 'E')
            E++;
        if (characterArray[i] == 'F')
            F++;
    }
     int[] marks = {A, B, C, D, E, F};
     return marks; 
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than snippets - and include the output as text rather than a screenshot. (After all, it *is* just text...)

Comment: You might also want to ask yourself what you expect `grades [i] = i;` to do... you're ignoring the `n` parameter except to find out how large it is.

Comment: (It's not clear why you have a `grades` array at all in `getGrades`, to be honest...)

Answer (score 1):

```
 int A=0,B=0,C=0,D=0,E=0,F=0;
 int[] marks = {A, B, C, D, E, F};
```

Doesn't link `marks` with `A`, `B` etc.
When you increment `A` `marks` stays unchanged.

I suggest you to construct `marks` after all calculation is done. Simply put `int[] marks = {A, B, C, D, E, F};` just before return.

PS: `if (characterArray[i] == 'B') A++;` looks wrong for me.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply guys, I am actually amazed by how helpful and quick the community is here. I have attempted to fix the return array marks[] but still getting output of 1 for all values on output.

Answer (score 0):

Since @talex explained what is wrong with your code I can point you to a better solution: since your `grades` are sequence of letters they can be matched to an array of length `'F' - 'A' + 1` (number of letters between `'A'` and `'F'`). The matching function would be as easy as it can be: use `grade - 'A'` as index for an array and `i + 'A'` as a restoration function.